# Issue with installing new module for adding custom attribute into category section magento 2

Tags: magento2

I have created new module for adding custom attribute for category section in admin area of Magento 2. After that when I tried to run the `setup:upgrade` command  it gives us the following errors on `fallback.php`

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   /vendor/magento/module-store/Model/Config/Processor/Fallback.php on
>   line 125

Also I have checked the `app/etc/env.php` file it looks like working but I don't understand how can we resolve this issue. So please suggest and help that will be great for me.

Comment: Can you please add code which creates category attribute?

Comment: Yes. I have added the below code for creating the custom attribute in setup/installdata.php

Comment: $categorySetup->addAttribute(
            'catalog_category',
            'additional_image',
            [
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'label' => 'Additional Image',
                'input' => 'image',
                'backend' => 'Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Attribute\Backend\Image',
                'required' => false,
                'sort_order' => 100,
                'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                'group' => 'Content',
            ]
        );

Answer (score 0):

Try Below code:

```
<?php
namespace Namespace\Module\Setup;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Setup\CategorySetupFactory;
class InstallData
    implements InstallDataInterface
{
    /**
     * Category setup factory
     *
     * @var CategorySetupFactory
     */
    private $categorySetupFactory;
    /**
     * Init
     *
     * @param CategorySetupFactory $categorySetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        CategorySetupFactory $categorySetupFactory
    ) {
        $this->categorySetupFactory = $categorySetupFactory;
    }
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function install(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
        ModuleContextInterface $context
    ) {
        $setup->startSetup();
        /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Setup\CategorySetup $categorySetup */
        $categorySetup = $this->categorySetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $categorySetup->addAttribute(
            'catalog_category',
            'additional_image',
            [
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'label' => 'Additional Image',
                'input' => 'image',
                'backend' => 'Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Attribute\Backend\Image',
                'required' => false,
                'sort_order' => 100,
                'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                'group' => 'General Information',
            ]
        );
        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have already used same code which you have provided here in installdata.php but still gives same errors on fallback.php line no 125

Comment: I don't understand how this was happening with my end.